# Managing Environment Variables For .NET Test

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables, open-source

I'm trying to use environment variables for managing credentials in my open-source .NET project. I don't want to share the credentials in repository, via a config file. I'm familiar with setting the values in AppVeyor, but not for my local machine. In the Ruby world we use a `.env` file for managing environmental variables. Is there a similar approach in .NET?

Comment: .NET configuration files, web.config for the web and app.config for application and services have configuration transform capabilities that allow you to maintain environment specific settings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the best way for me to handle this was to set the environment variables under System Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables. I can then set the same values in the Environment tab of AppVeyor.